# How to speed up the creation of a label tensor from label map in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Given a label map of dimensions W X H where each element can take values from {0,..,K-1} I want to output a label tensor of dimensions K X W x H where each element in the K'th map is 1 only if the corresponding value in the labelmap was K.  Currently my implementation uses two for loops and is very slow.

```
p_label = Labelmap with one channel

label = np.zeros((K,p_label.shape[0], p_label.shape[1]))
for i in xrange(p_label.shape[0]):
      for j in xrange(p_label.shape[1]):
           label[p_label[i,j],i,j] = 1
```

Is there a better way to do this operation in Numpy using broadcasting?

Comment: Is `p_label` 4d or 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `==` operator with broadcasting.

For example,

```
In [19]: W = 5

In [20]: H = 8

In [21]: K = 10
```

Create a `p_label` for the example:

```
In [22]: p_label = np.random.randint(0, K, size=(W, H))
```

`kvals` is simply an array containing [0, 1, ..., K-1]:

```
In [23]: kvals = np.arange(K)
```

`kvals.reshape(-1, 1, 1)` converts `kvals` to an array with shape (K, 1, 1).  This is compared using `==` to `p_label`.  Broadcasting applies, so the result of the comparison has shape (K, W, H).  It is a boolean array of the values that you want.  `.astype(int)` converts the result to an integer array.  (You can remove that if a boolean array would work for you.)

```
In [24]: label = (p_label == kvals.reshape(-1, 1, 1)).astype(int)
```

Here's the original `p_label`.  Note, for example, the locations of the value `0`:

```
In [25]: p_label
Out[25]: 
array([[3, 3, 2, 6, 2, 2, 9, 3],
       [1, 8, 1, 1, 4, 3, 7, 8],
       [5, 9, 1, 0, 7, 2, 8, 0],
       [1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 0, 9, 5],
       [5, 7, 2, 0, 6, 4, 5, 3]])
```

`label[0]` is 1 in the positions where `p_label` is `0`.

```
In [26]: label[0]
Out[26]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Label[p_label, np.arange(p_label.shape[0])[:,None], np.arange(p_label.shape[1])] = 1
```

The 3 index arrays broadcast against each other.

==============================

```
lmap = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
lbl = np.zeros((12,3,4),int)
lbl[lmap,np.arange(3)[:,None],np.arange(4)] = 1

In [5]: lbl
Out[5]: 
array([[[1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       ...
       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]]])
```